# Как установить слушатель кнопки OSM OverlayItem?

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap

у меня есть гео точка на карте Open Street Map. Я хочу на нее нажать и через интент открыть новую активити. Но я не могу на точку установить слушатель. Помогите!

часть кода:

```
map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);  
map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);               
GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(57.174103, 60.204252); //задаем координаты
IMapController mapController = map.getController();
mapController.setZoom(20.0);
mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

getLastLocation();

ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
OverlayItem home = new OverlayItem("Вы в Таватуе!", "тут будет информация о пожаре", startPoint);
items.add(home);
items.add(new OverlayItem("qlqpart", "lol", new GeoPoint(43.570815, 1.466282)));

ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<OverlayItem> mOverlay = new ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<OverlayItem>(getApplicationContext(),
        items, new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int index, OverlayItem item) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongPress(int index, OverlayItem item) {
        return false;
    }
});

mOverlay.setFocusItemsOnTap(true);
map.getOverlays().add(mOverlay);
```

}

Comment: А метод `onItemSingleTapUp` разве не для этого? Он и есть ваш слушатель. https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocAll/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener.html

Comment: Господи, вы спасли тысячи моих нервных клеток! Желаю вам огромного здоровья и семейного счастья!!!!